# How did Nicci know Panis's tomb was melting?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

As title states, Nicci arrives at The People's Palace and is greeted by Anne and Nathan (*Confessor*). She tells them she's there to see Panis Rahl's tomb, that she may know why it was melting. Where did she hear this info?

On a side note, I've been doing the audiobooks of the series. So, if these are abridged versions, that would make sense, since I'm having issues remembering when Rachel showed up to the Wizard's Keep with the Box, or when Jebra left. On that note, it is also quite possible I'm just forgetting those events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ***Chapter 58 of Phantom***, Nicci goes to the tomb with Nathan so can see first hand that it is melting:

> *At last Nathan reached a set of double doors with guards standing
>   before them. He gestured and the men opened the pair of white doors.
>
> Beyond was a wall of white stone that looked as if it had partly melted. "Have you been in there?" she asked the prophet.
>
> "No," he admitted. "At my age I try to stay out of tombs as much as I can."*

and a bit later in the same chapter

> *Such spells contained Subtractive Magic. That was what was causing the
>   walls to melt. Containing them by walling the place over with special
>   stone had slowed the process greatly, but had not halted it entirely.
>
> "Well?" Nathan asked, poking his head in through the melted hole. "Any
>   ideas?"
>
> Nicci stepped out, brushing off her hands. "I don't know. I
>   don't think there's any imminent danger, but this involves dark things
>   so there's a chance I'm wrong. I think it would be best to shield it
>   behind an invocation of threes."*

Comment: I'd forgotten about that bit. Though the reason for the melting was wrong, you still answered the question of how did she know.